# How to recover the editor area after executing "workbench.action.toggleEditorVisibility" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor, key-bindings

I assigned `ctrl+' ctrl+e` as a keybinding to the VSCode action `workbench.action.toggleEditorVisibility`. After executing the keybinding once, the editor area disappeared. But, when I executed the keybinding once again, the editor area didn't return.

I was trying out some keybindings in my `keybindings.json` file:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+' ctrl+m",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleMenuBar"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+' ctrl+a",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleActivityBarVisibility"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+' ctrl+s",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleStatusbarVisibility"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+' ctrl+b",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleAuxiliaryBar"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+' ctrl+p",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleSidebarPosition"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+' ctrl+t",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleTabsVisibility"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+' ctrl+e",
        "command": "workbench.action.toggleEditorVisibility"
    },
]
```

As you can see all of them have to do with toggling UI elements. It was all going well until I reached the `workbench.action.toggleEditorVisibility` one. It didn't behave like a toggle command at all, it just got rid of the editor area all together to never bring it back. The other keybindings worked just fine after the editor area disappeared (except the `workbench.action.toggleTabsVisibility` one, since it depends on the editor area being there).

As a matter of fact, what the `ctrl+' ctrl+e` keybinding kept doing after the editor area disappeared was bringing up the "panel" (where the 'problems', 'output', 'debug console', and 'terminal' sections are) without focus, it wasn't toggling it, it would just bring it up and that's it. If I took it down with `ctrl+j` then `ctrl+' ctrl+e` would bring it up unfocused again.

This problem just affected the current VSCode session, thus, I could open other project with normality, but if I tried to open the same project in which I executed the previous commands, then the VSCode window became unresponsive at the beginning (sometimes with a warning message) but after waiting a few seconds it rendered in the same state as before: without the editor area.

Does anyone have any idea of what could be causing this problem, and more importantly, how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact problem that you had described, and this solution seems to work for me! and I solved it using this thread: [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/147042)

Basically, The editor area, once that command: *'Toggle Editor Area'* is given, becomes invisible.
But when you toggle it back ON, it does become visible but it is not aligned to center to our view.

So when I executed 
(1) command: **'workbench.action.alignPanelCenter'**  and then executed 
(2) command: **'workbench.action.toggleEditorVisibility'** (just use the same keybinding)
the editor came back into view!